# Animation sequence no longer work in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I got code that I did not write but need to fix. There is animation sequence that need to be played when the view starts. This piece of code worked perfectly in iOS 6, but after upgrade to iOS 8 the animation sequence do not longer work. Maybe you can help me find what is wrong and why it works on 6 but not on 8.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//bla bla stuff

[self initiateImageSequence];

//bla bla more stuff
}

- (void)initiateImageSequence
{
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("initiate", 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    [self.mainImageView setAnimationImages:self.zoom.imageSequenceArray];
    [self.mainImageView setImage:[self.zoom.imageSequenceArray lastObject]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Update UI
        [self.mainImageView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [self.mainImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        [self.mainImageView startAnimating];
        [self showMainLayer];
        [self performSelector:@selector(didReceiveMemoryWarningInSite) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    });
});
}
```

Comment: What currently happens? What do you expect to happen? What have you already done to diagnose it?

Comment: Currently nothing happens, what I see is what suppose to happen after the animation, what supposed to happen is that animation sequence should be played. What I've done do diagnose is check if array of images is full, and it's OK, also the check for printing with NSLog, and it seems that code is running fine.

Comment: Probable not it but I find it best to always do UI animations, changes, etc on the main queue or otherwise strange things can happen. I'd do all the loading on the background queue then kick off to the main when animating. I also suggest using     `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)`
 rather then creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can trigger animations on viewDidLoad as the view won't have a superview yet. Try viewDidAppear instead:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    ....
    [self initiateImageSequence];
}
```